# Good ruby on rails online explanations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have written some smaller rails programs before and am fairly well versed in ruby. Now I would like to find some intermediate explanations of the ins and outs. All of the tutorials and information I have found so far are a combination of getting started, for nonrubyists, and outdated; missing the more in depth explanations without having to read the source code that I am looking for. Any links/articles/online books/pdfs that you know that can fill this gap would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ruby on Rails Guides has a lot of excellent information:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

And as a nice complement, complete API documentation (has lots of examples):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 0):

http://railscasts.com - http://asciicasts.com

http://www.lynda.com (subscription based - and more for beginners)

Honestly though, I've learned the most (other than here) by digging through other people's projects including rails itself on [github](http://github.com). Read the source of some of your favorite plugins and gems.